# Not able to get Image ID of existence ec2 instance from powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to get the spowershell script so that I can pull up the image id of existence ec2 instance.

like :

```powershell
Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Blue "What is the ID of the instance"
$tid=Read-Host "Instance ID"
Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Blue "Input the region the instance inhabits"
$tregion=Read-Host "Region"
$Tinstancetype = ((Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId $tid).instances).InstanceType
Write-Host "Instance Type : $Tinstancetype"
```

Like in this code above, I entered Instance id and it spill out instance type. 
I need the code which can spill out Image ID.

Comment: You can retrieve ImageId in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only requesting the Instance Type property.
`Get-EC2Instance` will bring back an array of objects, each object has a number of properties. your command is only displaying the value of the  property `InstanceType'

If you run `(Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId $tid).instances | Select *` you will see all the properties and their values, one of those properties will be image ID.

Example of `Get-EC2Instance` output:

```
C:\> (Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId i-12345678).Instances

AmiLaunchIndex        : 0
Architecture          : x86_64
BlockDeviceMappings   : {/dev/sda1}
ClientToken           : TleEy1448154045270
EbsOptimized          : False
Hypervisor            : xen
IamInstanceProfile    : Amazon.EC2.Model.IamInstanceProfile
ImageId               : ami-12345678
InstanceId            : i-12345678
InstanceLifecycle     :
InstanceType          : t2.micro
KernelId              :
KeyName               : my-key-pair
LaunchTime            : 12/4/2015 4:44:40 PM
Monitoring            : Amazon.EC2.Model.Monitoring
NetworkInterfaces     : {ip-10-0-2-172.us-west-2.compute.internal}
Placement             : Amazon.EC2.Model.Placement
Platform              : Windows
PrivateDnsName        : ip-10-0-2-172.us-west-2.compute.internal
PrivateIpAddress      : 10.0.2.172
ProductCodes          : {}
PublicDnsName         : 
PublicIpAddress       : 
RamdiskId             :
RootDeviceName        : /dev/sda1
RootDeviceType        : ebs
SecurityGroups        : {default}
SourceDestCheck       : True
SpotInstanceRequestId :
SriovNetSupport       :
State                 : Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceState
StateReason           :
StateTransitionReason :
SubnetId              : subnet-12345678
Tags                  : {Name}
VirtualizationType    : hvm
VpcId                 : vpc-12345678
```

Your script will look something like this:

```
Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Blue "What is the ID of the instance"
$tid=Read-Host "Instance ID"
Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Blue "Input the region the instance inhabits"
$tregion=Read-Host "Region"
$Instance = ((Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId $tid).instances)
$Tinstancetype = $Instance.InstanceType
$ImageID =$Instance.ImageId
Write-Host "Instance Type : $Tinstancetype"
Write-Host "Instance Type : $ImageID"
```

Comment: awesome. it works. Just wondering about one thing as (Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId $tid) is not giving any output about image id but when we try to get output with ".imageID" it does give Image id. strange but working.. thanks..

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting? Have you used `(Get-EC2Instance -InstanceId $tid).instances | Select *`? Select * is an alias and positional parameter, full context would be `Select-Object -Property *`. It will override any templated output and display all properties and values. I don't currently have access to an AWS account with EC2 instances to test the output.

Comment: yes, after I add select * , it is giving me all the parameters.. thanks for clearing that up...